# Failover related issue in postgresql streaming replication

Tags: database-replication, postgresql-9.2, failover

i want to implement Streaming replication using postgresql-9.2.4 in my reporting application.I came to stuck on below scenario.
1)create master and slave with synchronous replication which is working fine.
2)Now i came down master and came up slave as master using trigger file on slave side manually.
3)fire data in new master which is working fine.

**4)Now My question is that how can i came up old master as slave which point to new master without taking base backup or using rsync ??**

my reporting application will contain large data approx 50(TB) and more if i take base backup or rsync feature it will surely take more time to sync old master to new master

is there any other way or third party tool which help me to avoid taking base backup ??
Actually i want to came up old master as quick sync with new master can anybody help me??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. as soon as you promote you database to master you break the link and the databases are different from there onwards.

The advantage of using rsync is that it will only transfer the differences, so hopefully it wont be too much!

The alternative would be to have a base backup that you never modify, but then you need to keep all the WAL logs from the master, since that base backup was created.